# Adding Sitecore 8.2 analytics contact custom facets in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics, contact-facets

I am working on XDB analytics code upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3. I have some doubts in custom contact facet. The below code written in Sitecore 8.2 analytics. I would like understand the below analytics code will support in Sitecore 9.3 or Do i need to modify the code to xconnect.

**Step1: StartTracking & IdentifyContact**

```
public async Task StartTracking(global::Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user)
    {
      IdentifyContact(ScUser);
    }
    
    public Contact IdentifyContact(global::Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            return null;

        string contactIdentifier = GetContactIdentifier(user);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactIdentifier) || contactIdentifier.Contains("anonymous") || Tracker.Current == null || Tracker.Current.Session == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
       
        //Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.PasswordValidated;
        Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("website", contactIdentifier);
        
        return Tracker.Current.Contact;
        
    }
    
    
    private Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User _scUser;
    protected Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User ScUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_scUser == null)
            {
                string username = _userProvider.Globalize(Sitecore.Context.Domain.Name, Sitecore.Context.User.LocalName);

                _scUser =
                    Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(username, true);
            }
            return _scUser;
        }
    }
```

**Step2: Getting Session contact**

```
public Contact GetCurrentContact()
    {
        if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.Session != null)
        {              
            return Tracker.Current.Session.Contact;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Step3: Fetching Contact from GetCurrentContact method**

```
   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact contact = GetCurrentContact();

   string searchFormatPref = _contactRepository.GetSearchResultsFormatPreference(contact);
```

**Step4: Passing analytics Session contact to GetSearchResultsFormatPreference**

```
public string GetSearchResultsFormatPreference(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact contact)
    {
        if (contact == null)
            return string.Empty;

        IFacetModel facet = contact.GetFacet<FacetModel>(FacetModel.FacetName);
        return facet.Preferences.SearchResultsFormat;
    }
```

**Step5: Analytics Custom facet Model**

```
public class FacetModel : Facet, IFacetModel
  {
    public const string FacetName = "Preference";

    
    public int PersonId
    {
        get; set;
       
    }

    public FacetModel()
    {
    
    }
}
```

**Step6: facet config**

```
<entities>
    <contact>
      <facets>
        <facet name="Preference" contract="Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.FacetModel, Central.Provider.Sitecore" />
      </facets>
    </contact>
  </entities>
```

I would like to understand the above functionality and code will support in sitecore 9.3 or not.

Some peoples are telling to use xconnect facet. If i use Xconnect facet I'm facing conversion facet issue.

**Example: XConnect facet**

```
public Contact GetCurrentContact()
    {
        if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.Session != null)
        {              
            return Tracker.Current.Session.Contact;
        }
        return null;
    }

 Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact contact = GetCurrentContact();

 GetSearchResultsFormatPreference(contact)
```

// Getting facet conversion issue in the below line of code  if i use xconnect facet because contact is coming from Tracker.Current.Session.Contact

```
 IFacetModel facet = contact.GetFacet<FacetModel>(FacetModel.FacetName)


 public string GetSearchResultsFormatPreference(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact contact)
    {
        if (contact == null)
            return string.Empty;

        IFacetModel facet = contact.GetFacet<FacetModel>(FacetModel.FacetName);
        return facet.Preferences.SearchResultsFormat;
    }
```

Can Someone please help me how to proceed the above code in Sitecore 9.3.

Comment: Sitecore documentation for XConnect and custom facets is quite good. Best check all the examples there and see if you need anything more https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-contact-facets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create the Custom Facet in xDB that will be saved in your `shard0 or shard1` table. After that, you can perform operations on those custom facets. You can find below listed documentation for more understandings:

- [Create Custom Facet Model in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/create-custom-facet-model-in-sitecore-9.html)
- [Work with Custom Facet in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/work-with-custom-facet-in-sitecore-9.html)

A method CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs() in Sitecore.Analytics interface is used to make your contact from Unknown (Anonymous) to Known.